# How to Show an AR animation on a marker-qualcomm SDK?

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I am trying out Qualcomm SDK (vuforia) for AR and Marker technology. I downloaded the sample marker recognition (ImageTargets) app and was able to create a sample app by my customized markers and AR images to replace marker.

Now I want to show an animation (a swf or a gif or any other format), instead of a 2D or 3D image, when the camera faces the marker. For example, when a marker say a dollar bill is focused, I should be able to show an animation (currently I show a 2D or 3d image). I am not able to find any reference in documentation or a tutorial referring this on qualcomm, so any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using Unity. Unity provides good support for qualcomm and animations so is best solution to implement AR animations